# How to stop appium from clearing the Android app data?

Tags: android, selenium, automation, adb, appium

I am getting this issue after upgrading my appium version to 1.6.3 . Whenever I use `driver.launchApp();` command, **it clears the app data**, due to this I am not able to execute the next tese cases.

I tried setting the below Desired capability as well but still it is clearing the app data every time when I try to launch the app.

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
```

So the scenario is, I login to the application then relaunch the app and appium clears the app data and again the login screen appears which should not appear.

Below are the logs in which we can clearly see that appium is clearing the app data.

```
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Vinod\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","079a1ea4d037eeb7","shell","am","force-stop","PACKAGENAME"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Vinod\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","079a1ea4d037eeb7","shell","pm","clear","PACKAGENAME"]
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 23
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Vinod\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","079a1ea4d037eeb7","shell","am","start","-W","-n","PACKAGENAME/.ui.SplashActivity","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
```

Comment: It will clear app data as it is launching again. but is your application code handle these? If in app write code is written you should move to next screen.

Comment: @jiteshmohite You didn't get my question. With appium 1.6 they added (with previous version there is no code to clear the app data) code to clear all the local app data (including all db files and cache). Moving to the next screen does not make any sense if all data is cleared.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add below code in capablity

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
cap.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
```

It worked for me.

Comment: `cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");` does the task.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that this capability is set:
Although the default value for this capability is false, still its worth a try.

```
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
```

if it doesn't work please provide a code sample from your project.

Comment: fullReset is by default false. I didn't set any value for fullReset

Comment: What code you want to see? its just driver.launchApp
();

Comment: try this  .. capabilities.setCapability("dontStopAppOnReset", "true");

Comment: `capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");` not working.

Comment: `capabilities.setCapability("dontStopAppOnReset", "true");` not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the driver.launchApp(); statement then it should be working perfectly.

You do not need to call this method because appium does it for you when starting your server with capabilities.

Comment: Its not the solution I am looking for. I know that if I don't use launchApp() it will not clear the data. However, there more than 50 test cases in a suite which I execute. If any test case fails in the middle of execution, I need to re-launch the app and start the next test from the first screen. Hope you are clear now.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the verify apps via USB ( "Check app installed via ADB/ADT for harmful behavior") in Settings -> Developer options.

Comment: Yes I tried disabling that as well. But nothing changed. Its' the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

hope you got the solution. If not you can try this. Appium version 1.14.2

```
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, "False");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, "True");
```

Answer (score 0):

As desired capabilities are deprecated, thought this would be helpful.

using **.noReset()** and **.doesNoReset()** helped in my case, find full snippet below.

```
    var ltOptions = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
    
    ltOptions.put("deviceName", "Redmi K20 Pro");
    ltOptions.put("platformName", "Android");
    ltOptions.put("platformVersion", "11");
    ltOptions.put("udid", "aaa88c0");
    
    var options1 = new UiAutomator2Options();
    options1.setUdid("aaa88c0");
    options1.noReset();
    options1.doesNoReset();
    options1.setClearSystemFiles(false);

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    AndroidDriver driver1 = new AndroidDriver(url, options1);
```